# macro parameter to function

Tags: c++, templates, macros

I am a situation where I am trying to implement something I'm not sure is supported by C++.

Say for example:

```
class foo 
{
   public:
     type item1;
     type item2;
}

class fooList
{
   public:
     foo list;  
   type getFooMember(member)
   {
      return list.member
   }
}
```

Is there a way to write a function "getFooMember"? Essentially I am writing a templated binary
search tree. I am looking to store items of the same type, however, one object of the class will store by name and the other will store by month. I wanted to reduce repetitive code. The easiest solution I can think of is:

```
type getFooItemOne()
{
   return list.item1;
}
type getFooItemTwo()
{
   return list.item2;
}
```

However, my add and search functions are around 20 lines and I wanted to see if I could avoid that.

Thanks guys

Comment: If you are storing multiple items of the same type, you should use an array or vector to store the elements. much easier to access it that way generically

Answer (score 1):

The language feature that you're looking for is pointer to data member. The syntax is:

```
type getFooMember(type foo::*member) {
    return list.*member;
}
```

Comment: Good: a better way is usually to take an arbitrary projection.